# Deserialize JSON with dynamic key-value pair to class

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, json-deserialization

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "ruleName": "PhoneNumber",
    "ruleSetInput": [
        {
            "PersonCode": "85782",
            "PhoneTypeId": "1",
            "PhoneClassId": "0",
            "DiallingCode": "021",
            "PhoneNumber": "9321662",
            "Extension": "",
            "Status": "",
            "User": "2",
            "DateCapturd": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON won't always have the same fields in the `ruleSetInput` node. I need to map each value under `ruleSetInput` to a class with the following class:

```cs
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Type { get; set; }

}
```

As an example Parameter would be a list and contain a value of:

> Name: "PersonCode", Value: "85782"

How can I dynamically create this mapping? I have tried `Newtonsoft.Json` but the mapping will only work if the object that I am deserializing has this exact structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `ruleSetInput` a `Dictionary<string, string>` and then construct your `Parameter` instances from the key-value pairs using `ruleSetInput.Select(kv => new Parameter { Name = kv.Key, value = kv.Value }`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: With `JsonConverterAttribute`**

You can implement the `JsonConverter` logic:

1. Iterate each `JObject` from `JArray`.
2. Iterate each `JProperty` (key-value pair) from `JObject`.
3. And add into the array of `List<Parameter>` type.

For `RuleSetInput` property, apply the [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeClass.htm).

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class ParameterConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Parameter));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<Parameter> parameters = new ();
        JArray jArray = JArray.Load(reader);

        foreach (JObject jObj in jArray)
        {
            foreach (JProperty jProp in (JToken)jObj)
            {
                parameters.Add(new Parameter
                {
                    Name = jProp.Name,
                    Value = jProp.Value.ToString()
                });
            }
            
        }
            
        return parameters;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Rule
{
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
    
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParameterConverter))]
    public List<Parameter> RuleSetInput { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var rule = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rule>(json);
```

[Demo `JsonConverterAttribute` @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V18mUp)

---

**Solution 2: With `JsonConstructorAttribute`**

The implementation logic is the same, you can move the logic into the constructor by applying [`JsonConstructorAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm).

```cs
public class Rule
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Rule(string ruleName, JArray ruleSetInput)
    {
        RuleName = ruleName;
        
        List<Parameter> parameters = new ();

        foreach (JObject jObj in ruleSetInput)
        {
            foreach (JProperty jProp in (JToken)jObj)
            {
                parameters.Add(new Parameter
                {
                    Name = jProp.Name,
                    Value = jProp.Value.ToString()
                });
            }
        }
        
        RuleSetInput = parameters;
    }
    
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
    
    public List<Parameter> RuleSetInput { get; set; }
}
```

[Demo `JsonContructorAttribute` @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9EbsJx)